# with it come/comes?

Tags: grammar

I came across a sentence in [scientificamerican](http://www.scientificamerican.com/podcast/episode/salmonella-fav-food/)

> Summer’s here and with it **come** picnics, barbecues and of course Salmonella.

Why not **comes** but come? I found there are

> Here Comes the Boom. Here comes the sun.

When to use come and when the other?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because *picnics* and *barbecues* are plural.

Consider:

*Picnics come in the summer, the sun comes at dawn.*

When the noun is singular, we conjugate with *comes*; when the noun is plural, we conjugate with *come*.

> Every Wednesday, five of my friends come over – Jane comes with Harry, but David and Betsy come with Linda.

Answer (score -2):

The examples which you have given are present indefinite. In present indefinite, we use a verb’s first form. If the subject is singular the verb comes with ‘s’, and if the subject is plural only the verb’s first form is used.

Comment: Please explain what's wrong here, given the downvotes